# What is the maximum amount of tokens to burn using TokenBurnTransaction()?

Tags: javascript, nft, hedera-hashgraph

When I try calling `TokenBurnTransaction()` with 37 NFT serials, I get a return error *BATCH_SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED*. I am therefore wondering what is the maximum amount I can burn within a single function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of serials that you can mint or burn in a single transaction call is 10.

See this code sample:

```
// BURN 10 SERIALS IN THE NFT COLLECTION
let tokenBurnTx = await new TokenBurnTransaction()
    .setTokenId(tokenId)
    .setSerials([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    .freezeWith(client)
    .sign(supplyKey);
let tokenBurnSubmit = await tokenBurnTx.execute(client);
```

If you inspect the mirror node REST API for the corresponding transaction, you'll see all 10 mints/burns.

REST API (testnet is reset each quarter so you may not see the exact result in the future): https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/transactions/0.0.1218-1675178140-095602422
Here's a portion of the mirror node info:

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "bytes": null,
      "charged_tx_fee": 2546089,
      "consensus_timestamp": "1675178151.645157386",
      "entity_id": "0.0.3072409",
      "max_fee": "10000000000",
      "memo_base64": "",
      "name": "TOKENBURN",
      "nft_transfers": [
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 1,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 2,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 3,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 4,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 5,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 6,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 7,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 8,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 9,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        },
        {
          "is_approval": false,
          "receiver_account_id": null,
          "sender_account_id": "0.0.23223",
          "serial_number": 10,
          "token_id": "0.0.3072409"
        }
      ],
      "node": "0.0.5",
      "nonce": 0,
      "parent_consensus_timestamp": null,
      "result": "SUCCESS",
```